# problems with metropolis theme standout using pandoc

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I have been having problems with the metropolis theme where standout slides extend for the remaining slides ([see github pandoc issue #3007](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3007)).  I have found what appears to be a workaround [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4786) where a [modified pandoc template](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/commit/748aa920f6cdbe5c7f828a706a048eda8340abc7) is used to fix the standout errors, but I can't seem to make it work.  Can someone give me advice on what's going wrong?

System: WSL, pandoc v2.6,

I have copied and pasted the modified template into ~/.pandoc/templates/, and create beamer slides with the command below:

```
pandoc --pdf-engine=lualatex --template=template.latex -t beamer -o slides.pdf 01-\
Main.md
```

An example markdown file I am using is [here](https://github.com/SNTagore/documentation/blob/master/beamer-markdown-template).  The problem seems to continue on my computer, and nothing I do seems to lock standout to specific slides.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it to work, so I'll answer my own question in case it helps anyone in the future:

my previous mtheme.sty files were downloaded from overleaf as miktex doesn't seem to function in my version of wsl (couldn't use auto-package download from ctan).  After deleting the sty files, I rebuilt them from source as described on the github page, and changed the pandoc command to:

```
pandoc --pdf-engine=lualatex -t beamer -o slides.pdf 01-\
Main.md
```

(removed template)  has not caused any issues with standout so far.